# Couchdb replicator from Windows to Unix

Tags: configuration, couchdb, linux-mint

I want to replicate my CouchDB Database from my Windows computer (couchDB 1.5.0) to Linux Mint computer (couchDB 1.4.0, don't know why apt-get doesn't install the 1.6) via URL.

The tool "Replicator" in Futon create all views and documents.

Then when I want to run a query replicated, I always have an error :

`Error : reduce_overflow_error. Reduce output must shrink more rapidly`.

Even if I haven't reduce function.

So I try to create a simple temporary view on the replicated database (display rev value for each document). Now I have :

`error : os_process_error {exit_status,1}`.

If I create a new database for test, the query works...

Any idea to export / replicate easily my DB ?

Comment: This is a strange error... Can you show what query you use to replicate? You can do `create_target:true` to create the database on target if it does not exist.

Comment: sry for delay. I use the replicator menu in futon (_utils). From remote database my computer (where the DB works) to local database my new computer)